# How to use selective sync to delete a copy of a local file?

Tags: dropbox, backup

I've used selective sync and unchecked folders I no longer want saved to the local computer (to save space) but how do you do it for individual files? My work flow is, encrypt something that needs to be backed up, then copy it to the root of dropbox. Now how do I delete the local copy (but not the cloud copy) to save space on my hard drive? Only folders in the dropbox directory show up in Selective Sync, not files.